# where to find .NET upgrade-assistant logs

Tags: .net-6.0, upgrade, .net-framework-version

Im migrating my .NET 4.8 to .NET 6. On running the upgrade command on my project I got below message in `cmd` once it finished

> Complete: 145 succeeded, 50 failed, 7 skipped.

Now I want to see the upgrade-assistant.clef file for errors. But i dont know where to find it.

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Log should be available in working directory - https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant. If you are using Visual studio extension - then in `Output` there is section for `Upgrade Assistant`.

[Viewing log files](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant#viewing-log-files)

*The project outputs a log file by default in the working directory called upgrade-assistant.clef that can be viewed with tools such as [Compact Log Format Viewer](https://github.com/warrenbuckley/Compact-Log-Format-Viewer) available via the [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9N8RV8LKTXRJ?cid=storebadge&ocid=badge)*.